# How to change what port SolidJS server runs on in your local enviornment

Tags: solid-js

After initally setting up Solid and starting it with `npm start` it runs on `http://localhost:3000/`.

How do you change what port it runs on?

Answer (score 4):

`vite` is the package that is used to run the local server environment.

You can change it's settings in a file called `vite.config.ts`.

By default the setting isn't in there, but you can set it like so:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import solidPlugin from 'vite-plugin-solid';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [solidPlugin()],
  server: { port: 3001 }, // <-- add this line
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    polyfillDynamicImport: false,
  },
});
```

Documentation about this and other settings can be found in the [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-port)